# Como realizar um temporizador de 1 segundo?

Tags: windows, assembly, procedure, x86

Pessoal estou tentando criar um jogo em assembly x86 no emu8086 na qual as peças caem e é necessário um temporizador de 1 segundo para cada movimento da peça. Tentei implementar de dois modos:

```
 wait_time dw 0 
PAUSE proc
semtec:
    mov     ah, 00h
    int     1ah
    cmp     dx, wait_time
    jb      ino
    add     dx, 4
    mov     wait_time, dx 

ret
endp
```

E aprendi também usando esse trecho que pega 1 milhão de microssegundos que é o equivalente a 1 seg:

```
mov     cx, 0fh
mov     dx, 4240h
mov     ah, 86h
int     15h
```

Porém ambos não funcionam, o segundo estraga a tela inicial do jogo (muda posição da tela, altera a cor,...) e o primeiro não faz diferença alguma. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Como criar um temporizador de intervalo de 1 segundo?

Comment: O código  da chamada *86h* da BIOS na pergunta está correto e funciona sem problemas no emu8086. Provavelmente, o erro está acontecendo em outra parte do código, antes ou depois de chamar essa função temporizador. Como você está chamando essa função?

Comment: Oi @Gomiero tentei fazer de dois jeitos, coloquei esse trecho logo acima da lógica de descida da peça e também tentei criar uma proc com push's e pop's , fiquei até com receio que talvez o int 15h ah=86h mudasse algum valor dos registradores, flags e talz. Mas não deu muito certo, a primeira descida fica normal (rápida sem intervalo) e a segunda a tela se quebra e muda de cor. =(

Comment: Em alguns testes até deu pra perceber o temporizador funcionando, mas a tela do jogo muda ( ela vai pra baixo, fica vermelha e os caracteres são substituídos) . Se eu utilizar essa forma, ela altera algum registrador tipo SI, DI,...? Posições da memória? O que eu posso fazer para funcionar o temporizador e a tela também?

Comment: Realizei também um teste unitário nos registradores com push e pop ( acredito que esteja dando este problema por causa do registrador bp) se colocar push bp e pop bp aí a tela congela. (já não quebra mais e não muda de cor...). Tens alguma sugestão? Ideia?

Comment: a chamada *86h* não altera nenhum registrador nem memória no emu8086, e não deveria alterar nenhuma flag também. Sem conhecer o resto do código, não dá para ter certeza de onde está o erro. Há uma pergunta parecida no SO em inglês onde uma das respostas sugere setar o registrador *al* com valor 00h antes da chamada da int 15h: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089884/problems-with-bios-delay-function-int-15h-ah-86h

Comment: @Gomiero onde posso por o código completo? Podes entrar no chat do sopt?(publiquei lá no chat) https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha

Comment: eu respondi lá...outras pessoas relataram o mesmo problema, porém, ocorrendo no DOSBox e não no emu8086, e a saída foi mesmo setar o `al` para 00h antes da chamada.  Se você puder colocar o código em algum lugar compartilhado (ex: Github), eu posso tentar testar aqui.